# Magento 1.9.x Edit Billing Address Form is Empty

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am new to magento, I don't know why the edit billing/shipping address showing empty form in the Admin Panel.

Sales > Order > Edit Billing Address / Shipping Address

I finally found the file in the backend located

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/address/form.phtml`

But when I try to add the field it only has this php code:

`<?php echo $this->getForm()->toHtml() ?>` in line 41.

Where can I edit the getForm()?

Is it a file someplace, or in the database, or in the configuration settings somewhere?

[image]

Comment: You want to add your field in the edit order and add order in admin am I right?

Comment: How to add shipping and billing address field in the admin?

Comment: under sale order?

Answer (score 1):

> Fatal error: Declaration of
>   Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Address_Attribute_Source_Country::getAllOptions()
>   must be compatible with
>   Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table::getAllOptions($withEmpty
>   = true, $defaultValues = false) in /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Address/Attribute/Source/Country.php
>   on line 35`enter code here
>
> Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table::getAllOptions($withEmpty
>   = true, $defaultValues = false) Function Defination change so here two parameter added so we need to change this defination in below 2 files
>
> /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Address/Attribute/Source/Country.php
>   on line 35
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Entity/Address/Attribute/Source/Country.php
>   on line 59

code change to

```
public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = true, $defaultValues = false)
{
    $storeId = $this->getAttribute()->getStoreId();
    if (!$this->_options) {
        $this->_options = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')
            ->loadByStore($this->getAttribute()->getStoreId())->toOptionArray();
    }
    $options = ($defaultValues ? $this->_optionsDefault[$storeId] : $this->_options[$storeId]);
    if ($withEmpty) {
        array_unshift($options, array('label' => '', 'value' => ''));
    }
    return $this->_options;
}
```

Comment: Please give an explanation. What your code exactly doing.

Comment: Here function defination changed in core getAllOptions so we have to pass that arguments in our called function like Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Address_Attribute_Source_Country::getAllOptions() to getAllOptions($withEmpty = true, $defaultValues = false) only after that also error thow from app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Entity/Address/Attribute/Source/Country.php on line 59 file so we have changes according to getAllOptions($withEmpty = true, $defaultValues = false) now we can checked its working. I hope this will help you. !!:)